# Deploying maven project to nexus server using git-describe plugin output

Tags: maven

I have several maven projects that deploy to a nexus server. I don't like managing their versions via the pom file, and already use git tags for versioning via git-describe.

I added the [git-describe maven plugin](https://github.com/lukegb/GitDescribe-Maven-Plugin) with the following config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lukegb.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gitdescribe-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>gitdescribe</goal>
            </goals>
            <id>git-describe</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputPrefix></outputPrefix>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and it works perfectly for `mvn package` runs - but when I use `mvn deploy` I end up seeing:

`nexus/content/repositories/releases/me/botsko/project/${describe}/project-${describe}.jar`

I tried to talk to the plugin author but it's been a few days and no reply.

How can I modify the plugin, or my configuration to property set the version during the `deploy` phase?

Comment: Have you considered using the `maven-release-plugin`?

Comment: Will it allow me to use git-describe to name the version sent to nexus, as well as replacing placeholders in the source code?

Comment: It doesn't really work like git describe, but it automatically removes SNAPSHOT, bumps up versions, tags, and pushes to remote, and deploys to nexus. You're actually *releasing* your artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a way to edit the plugin but I'm not familiar with how the maven plugin architecture works.

I solved the problem by writing a shell script that passes the same git-describe value to the maven deploy process:

```
#!/bin/sh
gitvers=`git describe`
mvn deploy -Ddescribe=$gitvers-SNAPSHOT
```

Just make sure you use `<version>${describe}</version>` or similar in the POM.